# Substring word in C#

Tags: c#, string, text, substring

I want to get the substring **XXX** and **ZZZ** from my result text in c#
Text form: (`"; XXX; ZZZ; WWW"`) but

```
Result.LastIndexOf(";")
```

Does not affect because I have `";"` char for separate two word
and I can't find index of first and second `";"` char in my word.

Comment: split by `;` and search  `XXX` and `ZZZ` inside the array given by split.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Split input string using `string.Split()` and remove spaces around using `string.Trim()`:

```
var str = "; XXX; ZZZ; WWW";
var parts = str.Split(new[] { ';' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
               .Select(x => x.Trim());
foreach (var part in parts)
    Console.WriteLine(parts);
```

Result is exactly as asked in the question and without empty values:

```
XXX
ZZZ
WWW
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution. Just split it by the special character.

```
string x = "; XXX; ZZZ; WWW";
string[] y = x.Split(';');
```

Now you have

```
y[0] = "";
y[1] = " XXX";
y[2] = " ZZZ";
y[3] = " WWW";
```

Comment: Have you tested this code? `string` does not have any lowercase-only methods and the actual `Split` method only accepts `char`, `char[]` or `string[]` as a delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, solved.

```
string[] ResultTemp = Result.Split(new char[] { ';' });

foreach (string a in ResultTemp) {
    if (a !="") {
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(a);
    }
}
```