# How can I extract sub-string from string in c# code?

Tags: c#, string, substring

How can I extract this sub-string "60684" from this string "/fa/Viewer/Switcher/60684/0" in c#?

Comment: What did you try? We are not a coding service. You are supposed to post your best try and an explanation where you are stuck.

Comment: Please read [Ask] and Take the [Tour].  Also you might want to take a moment to accept some of the past answers you have gotten,  Accepting answers closes old questions and removes them from the Unanswered list.  Voting helps others find good answers

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Substring word in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34115239/substring-word-in-c-sharp)

Comment: The solution depends on the exact conditions. Is the substring always in the same position in the url or is it always the first number or does it always appear after "Switcher/" or , or, or... ? Difficult to give an accurate answer without knowing the exact context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Split` method :

```
   string str = "/fa/12012/Switcher/60684/0";
   string str2 = str.Split('/')[4];
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use regex:

```
static void Main()
{
    string pattern = @"\/[a-zA-Z]+\/[a-zA-Z]+\/[a-zA-Z]+\/([0-9]+)\/[a-z0-9]+";
    var regex = new Regex(pattern);
    string path = "/fa/Viewer/Switcher/60684/0";
    var match = regex.Match(path);
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1].ToString());
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Like this:

```
 string url = @"/fa/12012/Switcher/60684/0";
 string[] NumberAfterSwitcher = url.Split('/');
 string num = (NumberAfterSwitcher.Length > 3) ? (String)url.Split('/').GetValue(3) : String.Empty;
```